# If Request responds with invalid OAuth key then generate new key

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, axios

I have a React Native Frontend & Express.js backend. My backend calls a 3rd party API, to use this API you must provide an OAuth key for that user which expires every 2 hours. Sometimes when I call the API it returns with a 400 error saying OAuth is expired and if it has then generate a new OAuth key and save on Frontend. How can I add a check to all my Axios requests to see if the OAuth key has expired. Is this better to handle on the Frontend or Backend?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a [try-chatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement to check if the key throws any errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).